# woocommerce save checkout custom special field to user meta

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I'm adding custom special fields to the checkout page through

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', custom_woocommerce_checkout_fields');


function custom_woocommerce_checkout_fields(){
  ... //other code
  $fields = array("field_1", ..., "field_n"); //pseudocode
  foreach ($fields as $key => $field) {
            $class = $i % 2 == 0 ? array('form-row-first') : array('form-row-last');
            woocommerce_form_field($key, array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'class' => $class,
                'label' => $labels[$i],
                'placeholder' => __('placeholder cm', 'woothemes'),
                'validate' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'custom_attributes' => array('disabled' => true)
            ), $field);
            $i++;
        }
}
```

and it works perfectly. My goal is now to save this information to the user meta once he concludes the order whether is already registered or not.

To achieve this I'm using

```
  add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta','checkout_update_user_fields');

function checkout_update_user_fields($user_id){
   if($user_id){
        foreach ($fields as $field) { //the fields are the same as before
            if (!empty($_POST[$field])) {
                update_user_meta($user_id, $field, sanitize_text_field($_POST[$field]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that the `$_POST` variable does not contain the custom fields that I inserted inside the checkout form.

Why is this happening? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the most stupid man in the world; `disabled` `input` are not posted.

Hope this will save time to someone

Comment: You're added checkout fields look kind of whacky in the code you provided, but I'm glad you sorted it out.

Comment: What's whacky? Open to suggestions :D

Comment: You should use "readonly" attribute to achieve the same results

Comment: I think I was mostly confused by your "pseudo" code and using `woocommerce_form_field` directly in the filter. I've written a tutorial on [customizing the checkout fields](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/) if that helps.